# Crosswalk call Java method from JavaScript

Tags: java, android, cordova, webview, crosswalk-runtime

I'm using crosswalk now. I need to call a Java method when a user clicks a button in the HTML, which may look like:

```
<a href="#" onclick="callJava()">Start</a>
```

I'm not sure if [Crosswalk extension](https://github.com/crosswalk-project/crosswalk-samples/tree/master/extensions-android) is what I wanted, which seems to be so heavy-weighted just for calling a Java function.

Is there a simpler way to do this? Or should I use Cordova with Crosswalk in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are only using XWalkView as an embedded view, the `addJavascriptInterface` is sufficient to inject Java object into XWalkView(JavaScript),  which is just like the `addJavascriptInterface` in android.webkit.WebView:

https://crosswalk-project.org/apis/embeddingapidocs_v2/reference/org/xwalk/core/XWalkView.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#BindingJavaScript

Comment: Ovilia or @Shouqun I tried to get it working for one day! Please if it works for you share a code example. I'm begging you.. I'm under hurry and nohing I tried today worked -_-

Comment: Olivia and @Shouqun this is the most logical thing I tried today but still not working: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27820474/the-method-getsettings-is-undefined-for-the-type-cordovawebview

Comment: @Ovilia could you help me??

Comment: @AlexStanese Please see if this can help: http://zhangwenli.com/blog/2014/08/25/crosswalk-calling-java-methods-with-javascript/

Comment: @AlexStanese, Have you make it work, check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/40925577/6521116

Answer (score 9):

Here is about how to call java function with js in the crosswalk XWalkView. How to use XWalkView refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40858878/6521116).

References:

[crosswalk-calling-java-methods-with-javascript](http://zhangwenli.com/blog/2014/08/25/crosswalk-calling-java-methods-with-javascript/)

[XWalkView manual](https://crosswalk-project.org/apis/embeddingapidocs_v2/reference/org/xwalk/core/XWalkView.html)

Below is the process to call java from js, and notices.

add this to activity you XWalkView in

```
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mXWalkView.addJavascriptInterface(new JsInterface(), "NativeInterface");
```

and this, you also make it a class

```
public class JsInterface {
    public JsInterface() {
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void act() {
        //do something
    }
}
```

and in the html page

```
<button onclick="NativeInterface.act()">Call Java Here</button>
```

when you import JavascriptInterface, take care, make sure you imported the exact one.

```
import org.xwalk.core.JavascriptInterface;
```

Not this one, this is for webview

`import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;`

If you import this one, this will cause no action when you operation on the page and below error in your android studio.

> 12-02 13:24:49.921 12376-12376/com.xxxxxx.app E/chromium:
>   [ERROR:xwalk_autofill_client.cc(121)] Not implemented reached in
>   virtual void xwalk::XWalkAutofillClient::OnFirstUserGestureObserved()

Usually when you import the JavascriptInterface, the first one is what we want just like below pic shows.

But sometime when you change from webview to XWalkView, you may forget to change the JavascriptInterface.

[image]